# Critique Feedback for flyer design

Tags: print-design

First post here. Looking for feedback on flyer I designed for our restaurant.

We are a very niche place at the moment, want to reach out and introduce our food to different demographics. Will be handing this flyer out at a Food festival we are taking part in.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please review the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and edit your question appropriately. General "how's it look?" question are not within acceptable guidelines. Questions need to be *answerable*, not merely opinions.

Comment: *Lose the exclamation marks!*

Comment: It bothers me the heading in the middle doesn't have the same amount of space on the sides as the list below it has on the left. If it's trifold, you probably can't extend the translucent bg color, but otherwise, I would totally extend it and align the heading with the list on left. Because now it just looks like you ran out of space. If you can't extend the bg color, I'd maybe try to stuff the heading in a smaller space widthwise by adding line breaks, adjusting font-size, tracking, character width, unless it starts looking too stuffy... and/or nudge the list to the left a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Preface: I apologize if this comes across harshly. **I only seek to *help* you in your marketing efforts.** If you are posting an image looking for praise and complements, then posting it at a design site, populated by designers, and asking for input, may not be the best venue.

---

**This "flier" is completely unreadable. Start over.**
Any time trying to improve this isn't worth the effort in my opinion.
That is *not* to say it's "bad"...but it does not fit the **function** of a flier.

In general, the function of a flier is to...

- Promote types of meals
- Promote a location
- Promote "Traditional Pakistani" flavors

Some missteps --

- **Contrast**

  - *Reverse* type requires a bit more effort to be read.
  - *Thin*, reversed type requires even more effort.
  - *Thin*, *italic*, reversed type requires even more effort.
  - *Thin*. *italic*, reversed type on a *low contrast* background requires even more effort.
  - The vertical type on the far right is pointless. It's not visible and is overlooked for the most part. In fact, I didn't even know it was there for quite some time. Again, low contrast.
  - Why does everything have an exclamation mark? Punctuation isn't necessary for a list.
  - **You are essentially asking viewers to *not* read things.** Realize, for a flier, you have about *half a second* (or less) to grab a reader's attention before they merely dismiss things and throw it away. Asking readers to expend even 1/8th of a second to try and read something means you've lost them.
- **Location Confusion**

  - Is this a food truck or a restaurant location???
  - Do I need to go to the address on the left and look for a building?
  - Is it a truck that travels and I should check the web site for locations?
  - Or is it a truck which is *always* parked at the same location?
  - There's a truck icon on the left, and the text refers to "street food", but the photo on right 2/3rds kinda looks like a structure? I realize it may be more of a "bus" than a food truck - but if that's the case the icon on the left *certainly* isn't fitting because it's exceptionally misleading.
  - Actual photos of the truck or structure from *outside* as it would appear driving up to it, would aide users in *actually* finding whatever it is.
  - If it's a consistent location, then that location needs to be much more prominent so customers can find it easily. In fact, a small map indicating nearby established landmarks may assist.

In my opinion, as this stands, it may be a "pretty picture" but fails completely to be a driving factor to gain new customers. You may seriously have the best food in the area and people will be thrilled when they find you... but with this flier, few are going to remember it 1 minute after seeing it. And even then, they'll remember that photo on the right and not much else.

Comment: +100 for truck icon/tables photo. It's very confusing, looks like a trap!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your input.  I think I will go back to the drawing board with this.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my opinions or what changes I'd make:

1. I'll use a bit more thick typeface for more readability. Leading seems a bit less in items, I'd increase a bit that also.
2. I'd break the line after word *Pakistani*. *Street Food* together looks better to me.
3. Then align the heading and items on left. Also, I increased the padding on left and right of heading by reducing size (I don't know the typeface so used a random typeface for example).
4. I'd also like to move the marker a bit on right, the truck a tiny bit to right, and marker + truck together a bit down. *(Don't move both items individually if it is a full logo itself)*
5. Unless there's a specific reason, I'd also align the address and website in center according to your logo.
6. Finally, I'll move all content on 1st page a bit down.

You can see all changes by comparing your original image with the following:

[image]

Also, if the image has more pixels in left side (behind solid pink color), I'd shift the whole image slightly to right side, it can help fix readability of T A S T E. And the hanging flowers from the room will appear more relaxed (right now it seems too close to edge).

When you'll shift the image, the bulb will get displaced to the edge, you might need to fix that also, for example using Photoshop clone, so it still remains on left side.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The overall layout is poor. The pink gradation from left to right and the vertically centred text in the middle panel serve to focus the viewer's attention on the ceiling in the right-hand panel, where there is nothing of interest. The photo shows no people, and no food. It's also tilted to the left for no good reason, and together with the high point of view, it looks uncomfortable and ​unwelcoming.

The slogan ("Enjoy Pakistani Street Food in a friendly relaxed setting") is uninspiring. Why do "Street" and "Food" start with capital letters? For that matter, why isn't there a capital letter at the start of "Drive" in the address? The picture of the van is nice, but needs explanation. Why is there a pin icon floating above it?

I would suggest drawing a bit of inspiration from other companies in the food business. For example, Wagamama knows how to do marketing properly.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but I maybe have some tips and tricks anyways. :)

- Lose the exclamation marks
- Use a high-res version of the logo (it looks too pixelated)
- Try out different weights in the typography. Some more contrast would be nice